is there a pure c/c++ MWPM decoder
I understand that PyMatching has a main c++ core with all sorts of python wrappers.
Is there an example that shows how to use it in a pure c++ environment. I think the python part integrates an interface to STIM (which also has a c/c++ version). What I'd like to do is simulate a code (surface code for starters) in a depolarizing channel (no circuit noise)...without STIM probably better (simpler) but using STIM if there's no other way. The main objective is to do everything in c/c++.

PyMatching at its core is just a C++ MWPM decoder. There's a python API on top of that, but you don't have to use it. See the pymatching developer documentation from the pymatching github repo for instructions on building it or linking to it using cmake or bazel.
The C++ code does depend on stim's C++ library, but only for data formats (i.e. in order to parse detector error models and detection event data). You could write custom C++ code to produce the decoder data structures, and drive them with your own read/write loop, at which point it would be possible to delete the stim dependency.

I wish things were a bit more modular, but I'll see what I can do. Do you know of a good reference curve for logical error rate vs physical error rate for any code in a depolarizing channel (no circuit noise) decoded with this MWPM decoder that I can use to check that I integrated things correctly.

@unknown Follow stim's getting started notebook and you'll get such a curve.

There are many plots there. I think you mean section 7 for the repetition code. Under the plot there's a statement that "the repetition code is immune to Z errors..."; does this make sense? The repetition code has distance 1, so it should completely vulnerable to Z errors not immune to them...what am I missing?

@unknown Working through the whole notebook will give you the information you need. You are correct that, as a quantum code, a superposed state stored in a repetition code is highly vulnerable to Z error. But the classical value, the Z observable, is immune to them.

i'm working my way through the other examples...so the plot in section 7 assumes a classical repetition code? and the channel is just bit flips?...basically just a classical repetition code with classical BSC channel. If that's the case then that may not be a good starter example. Anyway I'll see if I can get familiar enough with merging a depolarizing channel with no circuit noise with a surface code...
